# How to implement a interface function in a class

Tags: c#, interface, datatable, dataset

I am converting the vb.net code to c#. When passing the typed dataset from the entity class to the untyped dataset params which is available in the dataaccess I am getting a error in C# but vb.net I am not getting the error.

One function declared in INTERFACE and i am implementing in one class. Through Google I found the how to declare a function in INTERFACE but  I don't know how to implement in the class.

From the function I need both the count and also the datatable, for that I have used ref in the function. How to implement the function mentioned below?

I would like to implement the below mentioned function.

```
int ExecuteDataAdapterDataTableWithParams<T>(IDbCommand podbCommand, ref T pdtDataTable) where T : DataTable;
```

Converting the below mentioned code from VB.NET CODE to C#

## Interface code:

```
Function ExecuteDataAdapterDataTableWithParams(ByVal podbCommand As IDbCommand, _
  ByRef pdtDataTable As DataTable) As Integer
```

## Implementation Code:

```
Public Function ExecuteDataAdapterDataTableWithParams(ByVal podbCommand As IDbCommand, _
      ByRef pdtDT As DataTable) _
      As Integer Implements diNonTransactional.ExecuteDataAdapterDataTableWithParams
  Dim ldaDataAdapter As IDataAdapter
  Dim lodbTrans As IDbTransaction
  Dim liFetchedRows As Integer
  lodbTrans = EstablishConnection()
  'EstablishConnection()
  Try
    podbCommand.Connection = coConnection
    podbCommand.Transaction = lodbTrans
    ldaDataAdapter = GetDataAdapter(podbCommand)
    ldaDataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", pdtDT.TableName)
    liFetchedRows = ldaDataAdapter.Fill(pdtDT.DataSet)
  Catch ex As Exception
    Throw ex
  Finally
    CloseConnection(lodbTrans)
    'CloseConnection()
  End Try
  Return liFetchedRows
End Function
```

Converted code from VB.NET to C#, but below mentioned code is not working since i am passing the typeddataset from entitty to dataaccess.Please help me how to implement the below

## mentioned function.

```
int ExecuteDataAdapterDataTableWithParams(IDbCommand podbCommand, ref DataTable pdtDataTable);
```

## Implementation code:

```
public int ExecuteDataAdapterDataTableWithParams(IDbCommand podbCommand,  ref
        DataTable pdtDT)
{
    IDataAdapter ldaDataAdapter = default(IDataAdapter);
    IDbTransaction lodbTrans = default(IDbTransaction);
    int liFetchedRows = 0;
    lodbTrans = EstablishConnection();
    try
    {
        podbCommand.Connection = coConnection;
        podbCommand.Transaction = lodbTrans;
        ldaDataAdapter = GetDataAdapter(ref podbCommand);
        ldaDataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", pdtDT.TableName);
        liFetchedRows = ldaDataAdapter.Fill(pdtDT.DataSet);
        liFetchedRows = pdtDT.Rows.Count;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseConnection(ref lodbTrans);
    }
    return liFetchedRows;
}
```

How to implement the below mentioned INTERFACE function in a dataacess class?

```
int ExecuteDataAdapterDataTableWithParams<T>(IDbCommand podbCommand, ref T pdtDataTable) where T : DataTable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface

```
public interface ITest
{
    int ExecuteDataAdapterDataTableWithParams<T>(IDbCommand podbCommand, ref T pdtDataTable) where T : DataTable;
}
```

Implementation

```
public class Test : ITest
{
    public int ExecuteDataAdapterDataTableWithParams<T>(IDbCommand podbCommand, ref T pdtDT) where T : DataTable
    {
        IDataAdapter ldaDataAdapter = default(IDataAdapter);
        IDbTransaction lodbTrans = default(IDbTransaction);
        int liFetchedRows = 0;
        lodbTrans = EstablishConnection();
        try
        {
            podbCommand.Connection = coConnection;
            podbCommand.Transaction = lodbTrans;
            ldaDataAdapter = GetDataAdapter(ref podbCommand);
            ldaDataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", pdtDT.TableName);
            liFetchedRows = ldaDataAdapter.Fill(pdtDT.DataSet);
            liFetchedRows = pdtDT.Rows.Count;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseConnection(ref lodbTrans);
        }
        return liFetchedRows;
    }
}
```

Comment: try {...} catch {...} is useless here: catch(Exception ex) {throw (ex);} does nothing but re-throw an exception. That's why try {...} finally {...} is quite enough

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I know that. But this was what in his code. So rather making him confused, I showed how the implementation goes.